# Android spyware detection

Tags: security, malware, antivirus

[image]I installed an APK which my friend sent through a link through instagram and as soon as I donwloaded and installed it, it disappeared into the background
And she told me to unlock my oem before installing the apk

This happened around late 2018 on a Redmi 4x satoni(I know I could buy a new phone but I want a solution)

I have the following deductions about it

- it survives a factory reset
- it cannot see or work when a VPN is on
- it has a keylogger and can see my entire media(vids,photos,music etc)
- it can read browser data

I only remember it has love in its name I think it has three words in its name it would be helpful if it possible to know what its name and how it works(if possible a link) (I did research before but could not find anything similar to this)
I have used almost all avs but no hits
I also got hit with sim swap which overcomes 2fa

(I think it's got stuck in the bootloader and I need to flash the bootloader separately please guide me as I've already flashed the phone and I can't tell for sure about it because I think it's a rootkit imo)
Thanks.

Comment: If malware survives a factory reset then the only good chance to get rid of it is re-installing a full firmware image (if such a firmware image is available for the device).

Comment: Try running kaspersky app. It will do manual scans in free mode. And add the result to your question.

Comment: Like I said all av apps come clean

Comment: Is it necessary to unlock the bootloader? Because my tech guy did it without it

Comment: It is almost impossible for something like this to survive a factory reset unless your device is rooted when the application is installed... What evidence do you have that spyware exists on the phone? I am not saying you are wrong, but the situation you describe is extremely rare, like being struck by lightning while being bitten by a shark rare.

Comment: @acejavelin any other theories?

Comment: Theories for what exactly? You have provided no reasoning or evidence for your assumptions...

Comment: @acejavelin Oh  my bad
My media has gotten leaked on the internet as my friends showed me and my all my accounts logged me out and the password got changed

I even tried flashing the phone without unlocking the bootloader(gave it to a phone repair) but it somehow still survives 
And to top it of i have made a Google account on the phone and made sure no backup is restored from factory reset and logged in with that and  it says a Linux computer has access to it while im only here with my Android so it's definitely compromised and I didn't share any account details with anyone

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this specific device, but if you have had it reflashed and then created a new account that exists no where else and you have no other accounts on the device or software on the device, I would suspect something more nefarious here, like a compromised WiFi network doing man in the middle attack or something. A device flashed with the stock ROM and no root access is almost impossible to be compromise directly and the stock ROM flash would (should?) eliminate anything in the device itself.

Comment: At this point if you truly believe the device is compromised... physically destroy it and get a new device may be the only answer since you have tried all the "normal" things to eliminate this issue.

Comment: @acejavelin But that's not possible unless it's Pegasus or some nation wide malware and I don't think the case unless there's a github source to make your own one

Because the malware was know when I installed it but how can it not be removed? Any such Android malware that you know? What could I have done that installs an apk to make it this bad remotely?
Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you are reflashing the device with stock firmware and it persists, then it has to be coming from the ROM image you are using, meaning the manufacturer is injecting it into the image as those are (usually) digitally signed, although I am not familiar with this specific device. Otherwise it is almost impossible to be the issue you think it is, and no, I have never heard of persistent malware at this level... it's not impossible but you are more likely to be struck by lightning while being bitten by a shark for this to occur.